# Unit Of Work and Entity Framework 5 Not Refreshing Entity

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, unit-of-work

Not sure why this just started happening, but I have a situation where an entity I am reading from the database doesnt contain the new values that were updated from a stored procedure before.  I see the changes in the database after my stored procedure makes the update, and I also call UnitOfWork.Commit to save any other changes.  I think make a call to get this item again, and the values are not the same as the ones in the database.  Any reason for this?  I am not grabbing this item anywhere before the update so I dont know how EF knows about it the first time I grab it after the update.

Comment: Are you disposing the ef context when you commit?

Comment: How are you obtaining your entity from the database (the one that isn't seeing the updated value)?

Comment: Yes I am going directly to the database using the repository pattern.  I am going to enable profiler to take a peek on my staging site.

Comment: Just ran profiler, and the data coming back is correct, so somewhere between EF and the DB the value isnt coming through.

Comment: Well it looks like I was doing a call before that does retrieve that child entity.  So now how to refresh the datacontext since the second call is trying to keep the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved some logic around so the item is updated before any EF calls.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess Entity Framework is caching those values somehow. I would try using the [`Refresh()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896255.aspx) method to force Entity Framework to go back to the data store with `RefreshMode.StoreWins` to ensure the data store values win.

Comment: I did on the parent entity, but they are child entities that were included on my repository GET.  Maybe a fresh on the child entities would work.  This hasnt happened before so its weird this just started happening.